# Exchange 2010 still sending NDRs even when disabled

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, spam

We have 2 Exchange 2010 SP3 Rollup 7 Servers in our organisation.  1 server receives all external SMTP mail.  Both servers have AVG Email Server Edition installed and operational.

I have disabled 'Allow delivery reports' & 'Allow non-delivery reports' from Hub Transport->Remote Domains.  I have also enabled recipient filtering of non-existent accounts.  I have checked via powershell 'Get-RemoteDomain' & 'Get-RecipientFilterConfig' that my settings have been applied.

I have also uninstalled the AVG transport agents.

Finally I have restarted the Transport service on BOTH servers.  In fact I have restarted both servers!!!

However, when I send a test email from my gmail account I still receive a non-delivery!!!  Aargh!

Any ideas on what I may have missed?

Comment: Are you sure the NDR isn't from Gmail's servers?  What's the NDR's generating server?

Comment: Yes, I've just double checked.  The generating server is our Exchange Server with error: #550 5.1.1 RESOLVER.ADR.RecipNotFound; not found ##